# MySQL Count all and Count distinct over 2 columns same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have the below query to count the number of rows with a distinct (customer username and store id) of the purchase of a certain item. How can I also count the total(all) rows where item_id = 3 in the same query?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT customer_username, store_id
FROM transactions
WHERE item_id = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(customer_cnt) FROM (
    SELECT customer_username, store_id, COUNT(*) AS customer_cnt
      FROM transactions
     WHERE item_id = 3
     GROUP BY customer_username, store_id
) t;
```

Comment: I was getting " Every derived table must have its own alias" before adding a alias after the subquery. Now works perfect. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing DISTINCT in your query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
SELECT customer_username, store_id
FROM transactions
WHERE item_id = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is a `cross join` of 2 inline views:

```
select x.distinct_rows, y.total_rows
  from (select count(distinct concat(user_name, store_id)) as distinct_rows
          from transactions
         where item_id = 3) x
 cross join (select count(*) as total_rows
               from transactions
              where item_id = 3) y
```